# Setting Ember.Select Default Selected Value

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am attempting to set the default selected value of a select box generated via `{{view Em.Select}}` which should be a pretty simple task according to documentation either setting `valueBinding` to the appropriate value or `selecitonBinding` to the full object represented by the item.

Sample code here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/p2dtx/2/

HTML

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">

    {{outlet}}

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

    !{{dafaultOption}}!

    {{view Em.Select prompt="test" contentBinding="controllers.option.content" optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.id" valueBinding="dafaultOption" }}
</script>
```

JS

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
    dafaultOption: 'OP2',
    needs:['option']  
});

App.Option = DS.Model.extend({ 
    name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Option.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 'OP1',
        name: 'Option 1'
    },
    {
        id: 'OP2',
        name: 'Option 2'
    }
];

App.OptionController = Em.Controller.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set('model', this.get('store').find('option'))
    }
})
```

Note on page load the value between the !! is empty, despite `defaultOption` being set to 'OP2' in the IndexController declaration. If I remove the `valueBinding` option from `{{view Em.Select}}` OP2 is output between the !! as expected, which leads me to believe that when the select is being rendered it is setting the `indexController.defaultOption` to null (prompt option).  When I change the select manually the value updates as expected.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `selectionBinding` is the right parameter to set on a `Ember.Select` but it should be an item contained in the array you pass to its `contentBinding`, so doing it like the following should work.

Define a property on your `App.OptionController` to hold the selected item:

```
App.OptionController = Em.Controller.extend({
  selectedOption: Ember.computed.alias('content.firstObject'),
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.set('model', this.get('store').find('option'))
  }
});
```

And set this property as your `selectionBinding`:

```
{{view Em.Select 
  prompt="test" 
  contentBinding="controllers.option.content" 
  optionLabelPath="content.name" 
  optionValuePath="content.id" 
  selectionBinding="controllers.option.selectedOption" }}
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p2dtx/4/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll test it out but I see no reason it shouldn't work. The documentation definitely says `valueBinding` should work as well, perhaps it's out of date.

Comment: Indeed it did help. Works perfectly after updating emberjs to 1.0.0 and ember-data 1.0.0.beta2. Thanks.

Comment: I'm particularly interested in this detail: "... but it should be an item contained in the array you pass to its", because seems like my problem has something to do with it.

I do some object copyings in my code, so after some operations, the instance of selectionBinding is not the one in the list of "contentBinding" (no address equality here, although there is a logical equality.... I mean: if all the properties of the instance in selectionBinding compared to each element in the cntentBinding, there will be a match). ... How to make ember perform logical equality instead of address equality?

Answer (score 2):

You'll notice that your `dafaultOption` in the template is blank. This is an order of execution issue. The content for  the select is initially empty, so the the `Ember.Select` updates to select the matching item (in this case, none match because none are loaded) and `dafaultOption` is updated to `null`. Then your data loads and, as `dafaultOption` is `null`, no item is selected.

A working demo using ids:
http://jsfiddle.net/eZWXT/

Or you can use intuitivepixel's demo which uses object equality.